# The Equivalence of Non-Singularity and Invertibility for Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

In Lipschutz's Linear Algebra, he provides the attached discussion (see below) on invertible operators in $A(V$). Now, I understand the sketch of the proof that non-singularity and invertibility are equivalent, but I suppose I'm confused about the counterexample that he provides to show that non-singularity does not imply invertibility in the general case of potentially infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

My thinking was: $F$ is clearly non-singular because the zero vector maps to the zero vector. However, it is not onto because the constant $a_0$ is not present in the image of $F$. Is that it? It seems to me then that I am missing something, because then I think about the case of a finite polynomial vector space, $P_n(t)$. This would also not have $a_0$ in its image. But maybe this isn't a valid counter example because $F$ maps $P_n(t)$ out of $P_n(t)$ and into $P_{n+1}(t)$ and therefore this is not a valid counterexample to the assertion made about finite-dimensional vector spaces.

[Lipschutz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwIRk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Since $a_0$ is not in the image of $F$, the map $F$ is not onto.

The situation with $P_n(t)$ is no counterexample since $F$ maps $P_n(t)$ into $P_{n + 1}(t)$ and these two spaces have not the same dimension. The equivalence of surjectivity and injectivity of a linear map $F : V \longrightarrow W$ is only given, if $\dim(V) = \dim(W) < \infty$.

Comment: Perfect, that clears things up beautifully. Thanks!